# MVC with Windows Authentication when is the best time to add new users

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, windows-authentication

I have an MVC application that uses Windows Auth. I store the user's active directory GUID in the database for security/access writes to other data. If a user has an active directory account they are allowed to use the app, so I'm trying to figure out when the best time is to add the users GUID to the database if its not already added. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about when they first access the site? In the global application class (global.asax) you can put this logic in `Session_Start`. In that method, see if they're in the DB or not. If they're not in there, add them.

Comment: That worked perfect! Thanks so much. I ran profiler and its only running when the user first accesses the site. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Session_Start method in the global application class (global.asax or global.asax.cs) is a good place, because it only executes when the user accesses the site for the first time (in that session).

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!UserIsInDatabase(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name))
     {
         AddUserToDatabase(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
     }
}
```

Note that it's necessary to check the database first, because when the user is inactive for a certain period of time (I believe 20 minutes by default) their session will expire and the next time they access the site, the `Session_Start` method will fire again.